# Does $GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ have a normal subgroup of order 8, or 16?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, linear-groups

So I know any group of order $48$ has a normal subgroup of order $8$ or a normal subgroup of order $16$ (or possibly both).

I am trying to expand upon this topic, figuring which of these conditions hold for
$G = GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$, as well as the group’s composition factors.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, every group of order $48$ has a normal subgroup of order $8$ or $16$. This was already shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471365/group-of-order-48-must-have-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-8-or-16). The group ${\rm GL}(2,3)$ of order $48$ has a normal subgroup of order $8$, namely the quaternion group $Q_8$. Of course the special linear subgroup $SL(2,3)$ of order $24$ is normal, too. The only subgroup of order $16$ (up to isomorphism) is  the semi-dihedral group $D_{16}$, which is not normal.

Composition factors of ${\rm GL}(2,3)$: here is a hint. It helps to consider the action of the group on the set of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^3$.